# mod_rewrite rule not letting me link/view css files

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

In my application this is my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

The problem is when I try and view or link a CSS file with a URL like:

```
http://www.mysite.com/css/common.css
```

It just loads up my index.php page and runs my whole application which is not what I want.
How do I fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is just saying if the request is for a file or directory that doesn't exist, re-write to the index.  I think your path to the CSS might be wrong if it is getting rewritten.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. You are right. I just remembered I changed the structure around a bit in my application a few days ago and the URL I was using to get the css file was wrong.

Comment: Can you go ahead and accept my answer so others know it is resolved?  Thanks, and glad you got it figured out!